# Body params are not passed when using Express 4.0 and DELETE

Tags: node.js, express

Since upgrading to Express 4.0 (from 3.0), all my DELETE REST calls are not authenticating because i notice that the body params (where the access_token use to be stored in) are not available for DELETE calls.

Whenever i use GET/PUT/etc., those params are being passed flawlessly.

If anyone have any idea why it doesn't work for DELETE calls, please let me know.

Thx,
Ori

Updated:

so I figured out that because i'm using postman, the delete is submitted as multipart, hence, i need to add a special "add on", so I added multer (app.use(multer());), however, it still doesn't work, here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),

    morgan         = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser     = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    //session = require('express-session'),
    multer  = require('multer'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),


    // Create Application
    app = express();

// configurate the app
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'web')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(multer());
app.use(methodOverride());
```

and my delete function looks like:

```
app.delete('/api/company/:id/email',auth.clientAuth(), auth.bearerAuth({scope:[1]}), company.deleteEmail);
```

Where the "auth.clientAuth()" and the "auth.bearerAuth({scope:[1]})" handle authorization and entitlement.

At the same time, how can I have this "chain" of both the auth and the entitlements in the new chaining of express 4.0?

Comment: Can you show your code, including where you're using the body parsing middleware?

Comment: It is possible that you're having an issue because the body-parser module was removed from Express 4.0 and has to be manually included if you want its functionality in Express 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not showing your code, I believe you are not passing param as object. here is a delete example which works well with express 4

```
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var app             = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router          = express.Router();

router.route('/users/:user_id')
  .delete(function(req,res){
    User.remove({_id: req.params.user_id},function(err, user){
      if(err) res.json({message: err}) 

      res.json({message: 'User removed from DB!'});
    });
  });
```